# ¿Cómo coloco un icono en Barra de tareas?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el icono por defecto que trae C# para  las aplicaciones de FORM?

[image: Cambiar ese icono por un logo pequeño]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, el formulario tiene la propiedad icon que debe ser un archivo de formato icono.

Luego en las propiedades del proyecto puedes establecer un icono para la aplicación.

Puedes ver más detalles acá

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-an-application-icon-visual-basic-csharp?view=vs-2017